# Google Search with keywords in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, request, google-search

I want to build script by searching with keywords in search engines such as Google, Yandex. I want to write a script that can show me the results. I am trying to in this code but it turns me as an output  "No results found.". Although, I can use that script for Duck Duck Go search. I expect that search keywords on Google and Yandex and take this output.

```
import requests
import certifi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def search_google(query):
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}"
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=certifi.where())
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.text

def parse_results(html, keywords):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    results = soup.select("div.g")
    found_results = []

    for result in results:
        link = result.select_one("a")
        title = result.select_one("h3")
        description = result.select_one("span.st")

        if link and title and description:
            link = link.get("href")
            title = title.get_text()
            description = description.get_text()

            if any(keyword.lower() in title.lower() or keyword.lower() in description.lower() for keyword in keywords):
                found_results.append({"title": title, "description": description, "link": link})

    return found_results

def search_keywords(keywords, num_results=5):
    query = " ".join(keywords)
    html = search_google(query)
    results = parse_results(html, keywords)

    if results:
        for i, result in enumerate(results[:num_results], 1):
            print(f"Result {i}:")
            print("Title:", result["title"])
            print("Description:", result["description"])
            print("Link:", result["link"])
            print("--------------------")
    else:
        print("No results found.")

# Example usage
search_keywords(["instagram"], num_results=20)
```

Actually, I tried different libraries also i tried use with Selenuim with Driver but I couldn't do that. Here is an example of this code:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def search_google(keywords):
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True  # Set to False if you want to see the browser in action
    service = Service(r'C:\path\chromedriver.exe')  # Replace with the path to your chromedriver executable. I CHANGED THIS FOR STACK OVERFLOW.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    search_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q')
    search_input.send_keys(keywords)
    search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(3)  # Allow time for the search results to load
    html = driver.page_source

    driver.quit()

    return html

def parse_results(html, keywords):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Replace with the path to your chromedriver executable
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    driver.execute_script("document.documentElement.innerHTML = arguments[0]", html)

    results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.g')
    found_results = []

    for result in results:
        link = result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href]')
        title = result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3')
        description = result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.st')

        link = link.get_attribute('href')
        title = title.text
        description = description.text

        if any(keyword.lower() in title.lower() or keyword.lower() in description.lower() or keyword.lower() in link.lower()
                for keyword in keywords):
            found_results.append({"title": title, "description": description, "link": link})

    driver.quit()

    return found_results

def perform_search():
    keywords = ["instagram"]  # Modify with your desired keywords
    html = search_google(" ".join(keywords))
    results = parse_results(html, keywords)

    if results:
        with open('results.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(results, f)
    else:
        print("No results found.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    perform_search()
```

Comment: What's the issue that you're facing with these codes?

Comment: It gives me no results ouput. But for duck duck go search it don't give me no result. I cannot solve it.

Comment: Google has Captcha and other security mechanisms to detect these kinds of scraping attempts, so it'd be hard even with selenium. Try DuckDuckGo, tweak your request, and see which headers are required.

Comment: Change headless to False in your selenium code, you'll see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a captcha mechanism for halting web scrapers, which makes it difficult to scrape, but if you're fine with DuckDuckGo, as you mentioned in your question, here's the code for the same.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def init_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


def search_google(driver, keywords):
    driver.get(f'https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q={keywords}')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'article[data-nrn="result"]')))

    return driver.page_source

    
def parse_results(html, keywords):
    results = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('article', {'data-nrn': 'result'})

    for result in results:
        result = {
            'Link': result.find('a').get('href'),
            'Title': result.find('h2').text,
            'Description': result.find('div', {'data-result': 'snippet'}).text,
        }
        
        for keyword in keywords:
            if (keyword.lower() in result['Title'].lower()) or (keyword.lower() in result['Description'].lower()) or (keyword.lower() in result['Link'].lower()):
                print(result)
                yield result

     
def perform_search():
    driver = init_driver()
    
    keywords = ["instagram"]  # Modify with your desired keywords
    html = search_google(driver, " ".join(keywords))
    driver.quit()

    results = [result for result in parse_results(html, keywords)]

    if results:
        with open('results.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(results, f)
            
    else:
        print("No results found.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    perform_search()
```

In parse_results, you were initializing the WebDriver again even for reading HTML which isn't efficient, also hardcoded delay like `time.sleep` isn't effective, updated it to `expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located` to wait for the element to load. And updated filling in of keywords to direct search through the URL to make it faster.